# Hard Drive problem - Buffer I/O error on dev/sdb. Can I fix this drive or at least recover the data?

Tags: mount, hard-drive, smart

I can't mount my hard disk anymore. dmesg -w shows this kind of error.

```
[14258.478443] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[14258.620177] usb-storage 3-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[14258.620625] scsi host6: usb-storage 3-4:1.0
[14259.629271] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access        Mass  Storage Device        PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[14259.654286] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 976773166 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/466 GiB)
[14259.654484] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[14259.654488] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[14259.654671] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[14259.654678] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[14259.775713] scsi_io_completion: 18 callbacks suppressed
[14259.775727] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[14259.775736] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : 0x3 [current] 
[14259.775741] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 ASC=0x11 ASCQ=0x0 
[14259.775748] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
[14259.775751] print_req_error: 18 callbacks suppressed
[14259.775754] print_req_error: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 0
[14259.775764] buffer_io_error: 26 callbacks suppressed
[14259.775767] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[14259.843377] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[14259.843386] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : 0x3 [current] 
[14259.843392] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 ASC=0x11 ASCQ=0x0 
[14259.843399] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 02 00
[14259.843403] print_req_error: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 2
[14259.843413] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 1, async page read
[14259.868776] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[14259.868784] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : 0x3 [current] 
[14259.868790] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 ASC=0x11 ASCQ=0x0 
[14259.868797] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 02 00
[14259.868800] print_req_error: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 4
[14259.868810] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 2, async page read
[14259.894152] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[14259.894160] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : 0x3 [current] 
[14259.894166] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 ASC=0x11 ASCQ=0x0 
[14259.894172] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 00 00 00 06 00 00 02 00
[14259.894177] print_req_error: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 6
[14259.894186] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 3, async page read
[14259.919445] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[14259.919448] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : 0x3 [current] 
[14259.919449] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 ASC=0x11 ASCQ=0x0 
[14259.919451] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
[14259.919453] print_req_error: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 0
[14259.919456] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[14259.944756] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[14259.944763] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : 0x3 [current] 
[14259.944768] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 ASC=0x11 ASCQ=0x0 
[14259.944775] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 02 00
[14259.944779] print_req_error: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 2
[14259.944788] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 1, async page read
[14259.970120] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[14259.970128] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : 0x3 [current] 
[14259.970133] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 ASC=0x11 ASCQ=0x0 
[14259.970139] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 02 00
[14259.970142] print_req_error: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 4
[14259.970151] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 2, async page read
[14259.995547] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[14259.995554] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : 0x3 [current] 
[14259.995559] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 ASC=0x11 ASCQ=0x0 
[14259.995564] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 00 00 00 06 00 00 02 00
[14259.995568] print_req_error: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 6
[14259.995575] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 3, async page read
[14259.995600] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[14260.020959] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[14260.020964] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : 0x3 [current] 
[14260.020968] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 ASC=0x11 ASCQ=0x0 
[14260.020973] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
[14260.020976] print_req_error: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 0
[14260.020982] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[14260.046308] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
[14260.046317] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : 0x3 [current] 
[14260.046323] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 ASC=0x11 ASCQ=0x0 
[14260.046329] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: opcode=0x28 28 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 02 00
[14260.046334] print_req_error: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 2
[14260.046343] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 1, async page read
[14260.299886]  sdb: unable to read partition table
[14260.300948] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

Since this is a fairly new hard disk, I don't expect it to be a hardware fault.

Following the suggestions online, I performed an the SMART test on the drive. `smartctl -a /dev/sdb` outputs the following:

```
smartctl 6.6 2017-11-05 r4594 [x86_64-linux-4.14.15-1-ARCH] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-17, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Laptop HDD
Device Model:     ST500LT012-9WS142
Serial Number:    W0VC20VP
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 06a06b3ef
Firmware Version: 0002SDM1
User Capacity:    500,107,862,016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Mon Feb 12 13:18:08 2018 +0545
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x73) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 104) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x1035) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   113   099   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       53867432
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   099   099   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   096   096   020    Old_age   Always       -       5050
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   074   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       21598024463
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   093   093   000    Old_age   Always       -       6613 (201 84 0)
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   096   096   020    Old_age   Always       -       4993
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   078   051   045    Old_age   Always       -       22 (Min/Max 22/22)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1421
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1002
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       204738
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   022   049   000    Old_age   Always       -       22 (0 11 0 0 0)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x000f   094   094   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       5867 (9486 0)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       3
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   094   094   000    Old_age   Offline      -       5867 (37 14 0)
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       3729147456
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       564102414
254 Free_Fall_Sensor        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      4047         -
# 2  Short offline       Aborted by host               10%      4047         -
# 3  Offline             Aborted by host               90%      4047         -
# 4  Offline             Aborted by host               90%      3560         -
# 5  Offline             Aborted by host               90%      3560         -
# 6  Offline             Aborted by host               90%      2896         -
# 7  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       212         -
# 8  Short offline       Aborted by host               90%       212         -
# 9  Offline             Aborted by host               90%       212         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

I can't interpret the raw data but since all the values are above threshold, shouldn't I be able to at least dd data out of the hard disk? `dd of=/dev/null if=/dev/sdb` fails with the same Input/Output error. So does `debugfs \dev\sdb`

Is there any other thing I can try to do? The data isn't terribly important so I am willing to sacrifice it if the hard disk can be fixed. However if there is a way to recover the data I'd like to try that as well.

`smartctl -l selftest /dev/sdb` outputs the following after a short test.

```
smartctl 6.6 2017-11-05 r4594 [x86_64-linux-4.14.15-1-ARCH] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-17, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1242         -
# 2  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%      1240         -
# 3  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%      1239         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1239         -
# 5  Short offline       Aborted by host               90%      1239         -
# 6  Short offline       Aborted by host               90%      1239         -
# 7  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1238         -
# 8  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1236         -
# 9  Short offline       Aborted by host               60%      1236         -
#10  Short offline       Aborted by host               80%      1236         -
#11  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       298         -
#12  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         1         -
```

Thank you for your time.